# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error in this program. Beginner in selenium so wanted to try opening a browser through xmlreader. I have the xmlreader code and openurl(simply open a google page) in the local library. I want to call these methods in the [setup] and [test] by creating an instance. Any help appreciated.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;
    LocalLib localLib;
    [SetUp]
    public void openBrowser()
    {
        localLib = new LocalLib(driver);
        localLib.StartDriverUsingXMLReader();
    }
    [Test]
    public void url()
    {
        localLib.openUrl();            
    }     
}
public class LocalLib
{
    private IWebDriver driver = null;        
    public LocalLib(IWebDriver _driver)
    {
        this.driver = _driver;
    }
     public IWebDriver StartDriverUsingXMLReader()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\XML.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "settings"))
                {
                    if (reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        string parentBrowser = reader.GetAttribute("browser");
                        if (parentBrowser.ToLower().Equals("Firefox".ToLower()))
                        {
                            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                        }
                        else if (parentBrowser.ToLower().Equals("googlechrome".ToLower()))
                        {
                            driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\chromedriver2_win32_0.8");
                        }
                        else if (parentBrowser.ToLower().Equals("Iexplore".ToLower()))
                        {
                            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\IEDriverServer_x64_2.32.3");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } return driver;
        }                
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
     }
     public void openUrl()
     {
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
     }
   }
 }
```

Error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ClassLibrary1.LocalLib.StartDriverUsingXMLReader() in C:\Users\XXXX\XML test project\Class1.cs:line 52

Line 52:
    string parentBrowser = reader.GetAttribute("browser");

Xml file info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <settings>
     <!--browser info-->
     <settings browser="firefox"/>  
   </settings>
```

Comment: The node you are trying to read may not have the "browser" attribute, what is the contents of the XML file?

Comment: I have updated the xml contents.

Comment: Curious, why don't you just use `app.config` with `ConfigurationManager`?

Comment: @Arran.. Beginner in C#.. i tried, but didnt know how to use it. So tried it with XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the contents of the XML file with a working example.

Try using this as the contents of the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--browser info-->
<settings browser="firefox"/>
```

If you want to add more information you shoud add more attributes to the **settings** node, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings browser="firefox" username="abcd@yahoo.com" password="abcd" implicitWait="3" explicitWait="3"/>
```

Here you have a **settings** node, with the **browser**, **username**, **password**, **implicitWait** and **explicitWait** attributes.

Then from the C# code you can then read each attribute in the same way that you a already reading the **browser** attribute:

string parentBrowser = reader.GetAttribute("browser");
string username = reader.GetAttribute("username");
string password = reader.GetAttribute("password");
string implicitWait = reader.GetAttribute("implicitWait");
string explicitWait = reader.GetAttribute("explicitWait");

Notice that the attributes will be read as strings and if you need them to be integers you will need to convert them with something like this:

int implicitWait = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("implicitWait"));

Comment: Thanks. the xml part now works. but if i want to add more fields like username , password can i write it this way  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>
  <!--browser info-->
  <settings browser="firefox"/>
  <!--send log info-->
  <settings username="abcd@yahoo.com"/>
  <settings password="abcd"/>
  <!--timeout info-->
  <settings implicitWait="3"/>
  <settings explicitWait="3"/>
</settings>

Answer (score 1):

Confirm whether or not your XML file has a `browser` attribute. If it does not, or it's an empty string, `GetAttribute` will return null and you'll get a `NullReferenceException` on the next line when you attempt to call `ToLower` on `parentBrowser`. The other potential problem would be that `reader` is null but I think it would have thrown earlier on if that were the case.

By the way, `NullReferenceExceptions` are among the most common runtime errors in C# code. You should have a look at other similar questions because the problem is always the same, you have some reference type that you try to use the `.` operator on when it is null. Figuring out why it is null and preventing that or adding checks prior to using the `.` operator always solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was in the xml